# How can I run health checks on an external REST api that requires authorization with an API key in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-route53

I need to run health-checks on a third party API that my application depends on and be alerted if there are any issues.

I have tried using route53 but that doesn't seem to give an option to pass headers with the request. I could just use a lambda but wanted to see if there was a more effective way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AWS CloudWatch Synthetic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html) monitoring for this. The features of CloudWatch Synthetics basically fall in-between Route53 health checks and a full Lambda function.